# Nothing written in my file

Tags: c++, stream, fstream

I've been struggling with this for quite some time now, it might be completely stupid (it's often the case when you've been looking at your code for too long ^^'), but I can't figure it out.

So I have a bunch of files that I want to write to and the following code:

```
outfileMatrix = new ofstream(path+to_string(trialI)+".csv");
outfileEvents = new ofstream(path+to_string(trialI)+"events.csv");
outfileMeta = new ofstream(path+to_string(trialI)+"meta.csv");
//...
vector<string> v = getTimeHistory();
*outfileEvents << "Subject ID ; " << "TrialIndex ; " << "Timestamp ;" << "Action ID ; " << "Duration ;" << endl ;
for(std::vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i!=v.size(); i++) {
    cout << "Coucou" << endl ;
    *outfileEvents << subjectID << " ; " << trialInd << " ; " << v.at(i);
    cout << subjectID << " ; " << v.at(i) << endl ;
}
//...
vector<string> w = getMatrixHistory();
for(std::vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i!=w.size(); i++) {
    *outfileMatrix << subjectID << " ; " << trialInd << " ; " << w.at(i) << endl ;
}
```

The output I get will be just fine on the standard output (i.e cout works just fine) but my `outfileEvents` only contains the first line that I used as the headers. Everything that should be added in the for loop is not. Now I've checked the size of v, it is greater than 0 and anyway the `cout` prints the data just fine so that it does pass through the `for` loop, it's just that the data is not added in the file.

I'll be grateful for the help you can provide.

Comment: Have you checked if the stream [`is_open()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/is_open)?

Comment: I wasn't had enough time to check but did you close your streams ?

Comment: Do you `delete` the streams when you're done with them? If not, the data may never get written to the file.

Comment: I actually don't delete them, but i'm gonna try. However, does it explain why 2 out of 3 files are correct and not the last one?

Comment: Apparently it does make a difference, but then again I don't really understand why. Before you mentioned it, none was closed and it worked for 2 out of them and not the last one. Also doesn't explain why the first line was written anyway. Is that some kind of undefined behaviour when a stream is not closed

Comment: My guess is when multiple streams are written like that all except the last one closes themselves implicitly! If so, Good think to know!

Comment: Except that it's not the last one but the one right in the middle. That's what I've just checked. Well problem solved anyway even though I don't really know why. @DavidSchwartz would you like to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it and you get the rep :)

Comment: Why all the dynamic allocation in the first place, pray tell?

Comment: @LBesancon: `outfileMatrix` is flushed by each `endl`. `outfileEvents` doesn't get such treatment in your code. And you're not even using `outfileMeta` at all...

Comment: I'm using it it's just not shown in that code. But you're right, the endl makes a difference. Adding it to the answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neither flush, close, nor delete the streams. So there's no guarantee the actual write to disk is done.